# Where can I find a PHP-FPM RC script?

Tags: php-fpm, init.d

I compiled PHP on  my own computer, and I want to know how to setup a script to start PHP-FPM automatically. Can anyone suggest a script that will do this for me? I'm using a Ubuntu Linux server install.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As we have compiled PHP we should, I hope, still have source code. In the source code for PHP they very graciously included an init script for PHP-FPM. You can find it in `<phpsrcdir>/sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm`.

You can copy this file directly with

`cp <phpsrcdir>/sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm /etc/init.d/php-fpm`

and then chmod it to make it executable

`chmod 755 /etc/init.d/php-fpm`

From here, you can do `service php-fpm <start|stop|force-quit|restart|reload>`.

The script can also be found below just in case you deleted your source dir for php.

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          php-fpm
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts php-fpm
# Description:       starts the PHP FastCGI Process Manager daemon
### END INIT INFO

prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}

php_fpm_BIN=${exec_prefix}/sbin/php-fpm
php_fpm_CONF=${prefix}/etc/php-fpm.conf
php_fpm_PID=${prefix}/var/run/php-fpm.pid


php_opts="--fpm-config $php_fpm_CONF --pid $php_fpm_PID"


wait_for_pid () {
    try=0

    while test $try -lt 35 ; do

        case "$1" in
            'created')
            if [ -f "$2" ] ; then
                try=''
                break
            fi
            ;;

            'removed')
            if [ ! -f "$2" ] ; then
                try=''
                break
            fi
            ;;
        esac

        echo -n .
        try=`expr $try + 1`
        sleep 1

    done

}

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo -n "Starting php-fpm "

        $php_fpm_BIN --daemonize $php_opts

        if [ "$?" != 0 ] ; then
            echo " failed"
            exit 1
        fi

        wait_for_pid created $php_fpm_PID

        if [ -n "$try" ] ; then
            echo " failed"
            exit 1
        else
            echo " done"
        fi
    ;;

    stop)
        echo -n "Gracefully shutting down php-fpm "

        if [ ! -r $php_fpm_PID ] ; then
            echo "warning, no pid file found - php-fpm is not running ?"
            exit 1
        fi

        kill -QUIT `cat $php_fpm_PID`

        wait_for_pid removed $php_fpm_PID

        if [ -n "$try" ] ; then
            echo " failed. Use force-quit"
            exit 1
        else
            echo " done"
        fi
    ;;

    force-quit)
        echo -n "Terminating php-fpm "

        if [ ! -r $php_fpm_PID ] ; then
            echo "warning, no pid file found - php-fpm is not running ?"
            exit 1
        fi

        kill -TERM `cat $php_fpm_PID`

        wait_for_pid removed $php_fpm_PID

        if [ -n "$try" ] ; then
            echo " failed"
            exit 1
        else
            echo " done"
        fi
    ;;

    restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
    ;;

    reload)

        echo -n "Reload service php-fpm "

        if [ ! -r $php_fpm_PID ] ; then
            echo "warning, no pid file found - php-fpm is not running ?"
            exit 1
        fi

        kill -USR2 `cat $php_fpm_PID`

        echo " done"
    ;;

    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|force-quit|restart|reload}"
        exit 1
    ;;

esac
```